# kml - animating radar data on Google Maps V3

Tags: google-maps, kml, kmz

I working on a website that utilizes a Google Map (V3). What I'm looking to do is apply KML layers, provided by the National Weather Service (NWS) at http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/kmzgenerator.php. I am able to get "single images," or still KML files to work, but I want to have the radar animating over time. The NWS provides KMZ loop files, and I've tried just simply adding those, but that doesn't show any KML Layers at all. Thanks in advance for any help